Optimizing multiple variables to get multiples output variable in Python
I'm working on a project where I need to find the correct value of 7 different variables to get 7 output values of a function and I can't find a way to optimize these values.
Let me clarify with the code:
ajustement_value = {}
def calcul(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7):
    arr = []
    ajustement_value["x1"] = x1     # we set all the values of the parameters used in the function calcul_verre
    ajustement_value["x2"] = x2     # these values are not passed in parameters but defined globally
    ajustement_value["x3"] = x3     # so we just set them here
    ajustement_value["x4"] = x4
    ajustement_value["x5"] = x5
    ajustement_value["x6"] = x6
    ajustement_value["x7"] = x7
    for elem in ajustement_value:
        arr.append(round(calcul_verre(elem)*100,2)) # the calcul_verre function takes in param the name of the element we want to get the value ("x1", "x2",...)
    return arr      # will return something like that: [10.05, 4.92, 4.0, 3.88, 0.95, 0.65, 5.34]

# the desired output are defined in a dictionary like this: bound{"x1": [lower_bound, upper_bound, average], "x2":...}
desired_outputs = [bound["x1"][2], bound["x2"][2], bound["x3"][2], bound["x4"][2], bound["x5"][2], bound["x6"][2], bound["x7"][2]]
true_output = calcul(values_to_optimize) 

Here the calcul(...) function takes in 7 parameters and returns an array of 7 values, each of these input parameters have an impact on the output values as these are what we use to modulate the result.
The output array has for target to reach the values defined in the desired_outputs array as close as possible and must not be outside the lower and upper bound defined in the same array by replacing the index to 0 or 1 respectively.
So my question is, how can I put this in python code to get the proper results?
I have tried to use scipy.minimize to resolve this but I always end up with wrong results or it just stayed at the initial parameters I gave it without optimizing anything and I don't understand how it works enough to find my problem.
Thanks in advance

I think scipy.minimize() is the tool for this. Is it possible the formula is chaotic and doesn't have a minimum that can be determined numerically?

The formula is right and I get the same results everytime when I run it manually, nothing is random in it, and yeah the minimize() function is most likely what I need but I don't understand how to apply it to my problem which is why I'm asking here.
